# prevent chrome from automatic text-align: right for arabic language

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, arabic

When switching the Chrome browser language to Arabic all elements in the HTML page automatically get "text-align: right" and "direction: rtl".  The direction is fine but the text-align is really a problem and I would like to prevent it.

How is it possible to prevent Chrome from automatically rewriting all of these elements?  I have tried to add "text-align: center !important" to the elements that I would like to remain centered but Chrome ignores them.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not coming from Chrome, it's coming from Google Deep Translate.  If you send in HTML with the target of arabic, it automatically ads the style= to all of the HTML elements.